# batch file that opens cmd prompt types string as command line

Tags: command-line, batch-file

I got my batch file to open cmd prompt and change directory successfully, however what I cannot get to work is after the directory has changed I want the batch to then to enter a string as a command.

I've tried `cmd /k string` but that didn't seem to work, the cmd just sits at the changed directory.  I've also tried:

```
    set Opvar= echo string
    %Opvar%
```

Again it just sits at the last changed directory.  The batchisp line that's commented out is what the string is that I want to act as if I typed the whole string and pressed enter at the current directory prompt.
Here's the whole thing:

```
@Echo OFF

FOR /F "Tokens=*" %%@ IN ('Reg Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList" ^| FIND "-1000"') DO (
FOR /F "Tokens=2,*" %%A IN ('Reg Query "%%@" /v "ProfileImagePath" ^| FIND /V "%%@"') DO (
set drive=%%B
    Echo    Admin SID: %%~n@
    Echo Admin Folder: %%B
)
)

:Ask

echo What are you flashing? Please select one option(1,2, or 3):
echo 1. Main Board w/ 6-Station OpCon.
echo 2. Main Board w/ 12-Station Opcon.
echo 3. OpCon Board.


set /P INPUT=Type input: %=%
If "%INPUT%"=="1" goto Option1
If "%INPUT%"=="2" goto Option2
If "%INPUT%"=="3" goto Option3

::::::::::::

:Option1

echo Starting 6-Station DFU flash...
echo xcopy "%~dp0M1k_MainPCB\6-STATION\*.*" "%drive%\Desktop\MainPCB6\" /d /s /h /v /c /f /k /y
echo cmd /k "cd /d %drive%\Desktop\MainPCB6\6-STATION\Debug\"

goto End

::::::::::::

:Option2

echo Starting 12-Station DFU flash...
echo xcopy "%~dp0M1k_MainPCB\12-STATION\*.*" "%drive%\Desktop\MainPCB12\" /d /s /h /v /c /f /k /y
echo cmd /k "cd /d %drive%\Desktop\MainPCB12\12-STATION\Debug\"

goto End

::::::::::::

:Option3

echo Starting OpCon DFU flash...
xcopy "%~dp0M1k_SWPCB\SWPCB\*.*" "%drive%\Desktop\SWPCB\" /d /s /h /v /c /f /k /y
cmd /k "cd /d %drive%\Desktop\SWPCB\SWPCB\Debug\"

::batchisp -device at32uc3a0512 -hardware usb -operation erase f memory flash blankcheck loadbuffer SWPCB.elf program verify start reset 0


goto End
::::::::::::

:End

echo ******
echo *****
echo ****
echo ***
echo **
echo *
echo Flash Completed!  Press any key to exit...

Pause>NUL&Exit
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are changing the working directory in a new instance of CMD (CMD /K), use PUSHD to change the working directory in your current CMD instance and POPD to return to the last used directory:

```
@Echo OFF
PUSHD %WINDIR%"
Echo I'm on "%CD%" Directory!
POPD
Echo I'm on "%CD%" Directory!
Pause&Exit
```

**Change your code to this:**

```
:Option3

echo Starting OpCon DFU flash...
xcopy "%~dp0M1k_SWPCB\SWPCB\*.*" "%drive%\Desktop\SWPCB\" /d /s /h /v /c /f /k /y
PUSHD "%drive%\Desktop\SWPCB\SWPCB\Debug"
batchisp -device at32uc3a0512 -hardware usb -operation erase f memory flash blankcheck loadbuffer SWPCB.elf program verify start reset 0
POPD
goto :End
```

...Or if you want to start directly the command in a new instance of CMD change it to this:

```
CMD /k "Start /W """" "%drive%\Desktop\SWPCB\SWPCB\Debug\batchisp" -device at32uc3a0512 -hardware usb -operation erase f memory flash blankcheck loadbuffer SWPCB.elf program verify start reset 0"
```

PS: Remember that you don't need to change the working dir to start an app, you can write the path followed by the process name like in my last example.

Comment: Hmm, learn something new every day.  Not too familiar with Push and Pop commands. Thanks for your post it was quite informative and helpful.  Cheers!